# Is there any way to override the (dark/light) user interface style of iOS 13 Context Menus?

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu, ios13

My app supports iOS 13 dark mode, and provides the user the option of matching the system appearance or forcing the app to always use either dark mode or light mode, irrespective of the system setting.

The app also allows presenting a Context Menu when the user presses a `UILabel`. However, when presenting Context Menus using `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` methods, I cannot find any way to override the dark/light appearance of the menus, nor the appearance of the `UITargetedPreview` view that animates when the Context Menus appear and disappear.

For example, if the iOS appearance is set to light mode and the user selects the option to force dark mode in the app, the Context Menus appear light. I would like to override that behavior so they appear dark - is there any way to achieve this? There seems to be no `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property associated with Context Menus that I can find.

The code that I use is below for reference.

```
// Setup code

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    self.textLabel.addInteraction(UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self))
}

// UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let text = self.text
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: { return TextViewController(text: text) }) { [weak self] _ in
        return self?.contextMenu(for: text)
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func contextMenu(for text: String) -> UIMenu {
    let copy = UIAction(title: "Copy", image: UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.doc")) { _ in
        // Perform 'text' copy
    }

    let share = UIAction(title: "Share", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")) { _ in
        // Present system share sheet
    }

    return UIMenu(title: "", children: [copy, share])
}
```

I force the appearance of the view controller from which the Context Menu is presented using:

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark // or .light
```

So, the problem I'm facing is not with the UI elements in my `UIViewController`, just the Context Menus that are presented from it.

Comment: The only solution I've found is to always add it to a UIButton and use the button's overrideUserInterfaceStyle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Override Light or Dark mode For the entire app or scene:

Add the following line to `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` in iOS 13 and above.

```swift
self.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light / .dark
```

#### Override Light or Dark mode For a specific `UIViewController`:

Add the following like to `ViewDidLoad`:

```swift
self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light / .dark
```

#### Override Light or Dark mode For a specific `UIView`:

```swift
view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light / .dark
```

Comment: In iOS 13 with scenes, you can't use the AppDelegate, you would set the window's style in the scene delegate.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for clarifying. I have updated the answer.

Comment: This answer is rather frustrating because it doesn't really to answer the question.  It offers some useful information related to the question, but fails to inform how to apply that information to solve the question.

Comment: `UIMenu` doesn't have the `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property and setting it on the presenting `UIViewController` has no effect on the `UIMenu`'s style. So this answer is simply wrong.

Comment: Question is about Context Menu (UIMenu), not UIViewController or UIWindow.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with UIMenu. It only works if that UIMenu is on a UIButton.

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, I was not able to override style for UIMenu populated on long-press on collection view cell via delegate method

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?
```

Context of my app:

1. On the iOS level Appearance to Automatic
2. Force needed UINavigationControllers / ViewControllers to .light via `.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light` (sometimes set on the navigationBar as well)

Tried to set everything related to collection's subviews or other views, simply everything which has `.overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property, and nothing. Long-press on collection view shows dark `UIMenu` if user has iOS in Dark mode. Shows light `UIMenu` if user has Light mode.

Comment: Same situation here.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer, just a "I have the same problem" post.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.flatMap { $0.windows }.first { $0.isKeyWindow } {
    keyWindow.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = darkThemeIsNeeded ? .dark : .light
}
```