# Overriding user interface style (i.e light/dark) on UIMenu

Tags: ios

I have a simple `UIMenu` in my app. As expected the interface style updates with the system. However, my app has the option of overriding the system interface style (i.e. light/dark), so I want to be able to override this default behavior.

There is no `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property on UIMenu.

I have tried overriding the user interface style of the VC, which didn't work.

None of the solutions from this post work: [Is there any way to override the (dark/light) user interface style of iOS 13 Context Menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919717/is-there-any-way-to-override-the-dark-light-user-interface-style-of-ios-13-con)

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: The only solution I've found is to always add it to a UIButton and use the button's overrideUserInterfaceStyle.

Answer (score 0):

You should override user interface style for the button

```
let optionsButton = UIButton()
let menu = UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: [], children: menuItems)
optionsButton.menu = menu
optionsButton.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
optionsButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.flatMap { $0.windows }.first { $0.isKeyWindow } {
    keyWindow.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = darkThemeIsNeeded ? .dark : .light
}
```